# Help! Im getting these weird streaks/cracks when I knife project

Tags: knife-tool

[image]

The longs streaks is what happens when I knife project, is there a solution or another method. I am trying to put doors on a plane fuselage

Comment: Hello, it's hard to guess what's happening, maybe share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots - what's the advantage of pasteall.org/blend over https://blend-exchange.com ?

Comment: Probably triangles/ngons, but hard to say if we don't know anything about your mesh.

Comment: @metaphor_set, with pasteall, the file is temporarly hosted, while in blend-exchange it is "definitely"

Comment: @moonboots - sounds like a disadvantage to me, honestly.

Comment: I've been told not to use blender-exchange because it weigh a lot on the server, unless it is important to keep the file for the question